# LaTeX Make Word Appear

Tags: beamer, luatex

I want to introduce words in Beamer slides one at a time. I learned to do this using itemize but what if I have simple plain words? I do not want the word from each segment to repeat I just want the new word to show up like such:

The

The cow

The cow jumped

```
\begin{frame}
  \<1-> The
  \<2> cow
  \<3> jumped
\end{frame}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
\documentclass{beamer} 
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{How to use \texttt{\textbackslash pause}}
The \pause cow \pause jumped \pause and \pause bought \pause honey \pause liquor
\pause for \pause the \pause marmots.
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or

```
\documentclass{beamer} 
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{How to use \texttt{\textbackslash pause}}
The \pause \alt<4->{koala}{cow} \pause jumped \pause and \pause bought \pause honey \pause liquor
\pause for \pause the \pause marmots.
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I do not know if I should ask this as a separate question but let us say that slide 1 is "the"; slide 2 is "the cow" and slide 3 is "the marmot" in this case I want to replace "cow" with "marmot" is this a possibility? should i ask a new question?

Comment: @Oscar You could do `The \pause \only<2-3>{cow}\only<4->{marmot} \pause jumped \pause and \pause bought \pause honey \pause liquor
\pause for \pause the \pause marmots.`. Of course depending on the ultimate aim `\pause` may not be the best choice.

Comment: truly amazing marmot!